# Difference between ajax failure and error?

Tags: ajax

While using ajax I am familiar with error, which is used to throw any error occured while running the ajax function, so why is failure used?

```
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'Webstore.aspx/FetchSlider',
                    data: '{"_CompanyId":' + _CompanyId + ',"_ShopId":' + _ShopId + '}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        -- code
                    },
                    failure: function (msg) {
                        -- code
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        -- code
                   }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked through the jQuery documentation, failed to find api related to `failure`. Are you sure that jQuery exposes an API callback called `failure`? In other words, are you sure that the `failure` callback is invoked when an ajax request fails?